# Implicit differentiation and rules

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

I'm supposed to write the rules used for some differentiable functions. I got all of them correct except for the last one which is $d(x^c)$.

I put in $cx^{c-1}$ because I thought it was the power rule, but my online homework says it's incorrect. What am I doing wrong?
$$
$$
The actual problem says:

"Suppose $u$ and $v$ are differentiable functions of $x$, and $c$ is a constant. Write down the rules (and verify them) for the following:"

Comment: Remember, it's implicit differentiation. There's something missing in the question that you're probably used to seeing. Find the right way to add it back in, and you've got the answer.

Comment: @user3213784 Hmm..what is it that I seem to be missing? Would it involve the notation of $dx$ in the rule?

Comment: Absolutely. We generally see a derivative taken with respect to something, like $\frac{df(x)}{dx}$ is the derivative of $f(x)$ with respect to $x$. Your derivative is not with respect to anything.

Comment: Of course..I should have realized that simple mistake since all of the other answers involved that notation. It's obviously $dx(cx^{c-1})$ Thanks so much!